# Rename package name dynamically while building through command line

Tags: android, ant, android-manifest

Is it possible to rename the **`package name`** in the Android manifest file dynamically while building the app so that we could release it for multiple clients ?

I want the app to build through **`ant command line arguments`** and I have a script that does it. I need to change the **`package name`** for different clients and I am not successful.

I have gone through the below examples on SO and different sites and none of them was successful.

[Android Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)
[Link 2](http://www.kpbird.com/2012/02/android-ant-build.html)

Can anybody please help me out to do so by providing an example code snippet if possible.

Comment: Switch to gradle, create a flavor, define an `applicationId` for each flavor, done.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` for example or similar command line text file manipulation tool or write script that does what you want in PHP. Perl, Python or whatever you like.